# how can i maximize Z(p,b) subject to some constraints in maple?

Tags: optimization, maple

```
z=(-1/(4*(-u+L)))(4*p^2*b^2*d-3*g*c*p^2)
```

given fixed values of u, L, and c, I would like to Maximiz Z(p, b) by finding best p and b, subject to

```
1-(2* d)/(p*(sqrt(g)+1))<=b<=1 
0<=d<=L
Min(c,L)<=p<=u
1<=g<=4
```

Comment: Hi joobin. As your question is written now, what happens if you copy/paste your equation and restrains into Maple? I don't get what I think you want me to get. Perhaps you could check your question again? You may want to [check out how to format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Inline it can be done with backticks ( ` ).

Comment: hi Therkel i got this message when i used Optimization:-Maximize: Error, (in Optimization:-NLPSolve) complex value encountered

Comment: Can I ask you to add the code you ran for that message? Also, to help yourself, I must ask that you copy/paste any code you use in Maple into here; and then test whether the code you gave us here works.

Comment: @Therkel here  is my code: restart; Z := -(1/4)*(2*gamma^2*c*p^2+3*gamma*p^3*beta-3*gamma*c*p^2+4*gamma*p^2*delta+c*p^2*beta^2+4*p^2*beta*delta-4*c*u*delta+2*beta^2*c*gamma^2*p^2-3*beta^2*c*gamma*p^2+8*beta^2*delta*gamma*p^2-4*beta*c*gamma^2*p^2+6*beta*c*gamma*p^2); u := 2; l := 1; c := .6; constr := {0 <= delta, 1 <= gamma, beta <= 1, c <= p, delta <= l, gamma <= 4, p <= u, 1-2*delta/(p*(sqrt(gamma)+1)) <= beta};
Optimization:-Maximize(Z, constr);

Comment: And what happens if you try to paste that code into Maple? It doesn't work because characters have been stripped. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47018921/edit) your question and add that code into your question. Put 4 spaces in the start of each line of code.